# Issues in Kali when connecting USB Wifi

Tags: drivers, kali-linux, virtual-machine, usb-drive, macos

I have installed Kali Linux on a VM on macOS 14 (Mojave) and I read that some of the kali tools will not connect to the host machines network card. I do not want to dual boot my Mac with Kali Linux. I am using the USB WIFI device - Zyxel (NWD2501) for the same. When searching the drivers I am not able to find any. Please help me with some links or solutions to make this work.

**Edit**

Link of the proof where it is stated that kali doesn't support build-in network card: https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-hack-wifi-password-using-Kali-Linux-on-virtual-box

Comment: Welcome to the site. Could you add a link to the page(s) where you read about the mentioned limitations of the Kali tools? It would make it easier for contributors to help you ...

Comment: @AdminBee thanks for the suggestion. Have updated the question.